# Using maplist with a lambda that does not have a body?

Tags: lambda, syntax, prolog, swi-prolog, maplist

Having a list `List` filled with numbers, I want to obtain a list of pairs `Pairs`, where each pair in `Pairs` is in the form `<number>-0`, i.e., each number of `List` should be followed by `-0`.

I came up with following solution to this, using `maplist` and a lambda:

```
List = [1,2,30], maplist([X,X-0]>>(!), List, Pairs).
```

Result: `Pairs = [1-0, 2-0, 30-0].`

While this works, the lambda `[X,X-0]>>(!)` just looks odd to me.
I know that I could also write `[X,Y]>>(Y=X-0)` to have something "useful" in the body, but I was wondering if I could write the first version without the "empty lambda body"? Or is there a way to avoid the lambda at all, without introducing a new predicate (I would like to keep the solution to one line)? Thanks!

Comment: perfect tagging! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative less 'intrusive' could be

```
?- List = [1,2,30], maplist([X,X-0]>>true, List, Pairs).
```

*edit*

Attempting an easy answer to

> is there a way to avoid the lambda at all

In my old naive interpreter, I didn't have maplist/N, since it was based on Clocksin-Mellish first book, where call/N was not introduced.

So I frequently used this pattern, based on findall/3 and member/2, to transform a list.

```
?- List = [1,2,30], findall(X-0,member(X,List),Pairs).
```

`findall(Template,Goal,ResultList)` is a bit the 'swiss knife' of list processing in Prolog. Since it captures all solutions of `Goal` on backtracking and *copies* `Template`, it performs a 'poor man' garbage collection, because the proof/variables/trail stacks are reset among `Goal` calls.

Comment: This is indeed the recommended programming idiom for this case.

Comment: As you probably know, Swiss knifes are no longer permitted on planes. And also `findall/3` produces incorrect results in the airy heights of reduced instantiations and constraints alike. `maplist/2..` does not have this problem. It might not terminate which certainly isn't the best. But at least it does not produce incorrect results.

Comment: @false: yes, I'm aware of some of these problems. Thought that 'poor man' tool was a fair recap of them :)